# Android Studio 2.3.3 Error Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-2.3

I have projet mobile already developed when i installed Android Studio 2.3.3 and i run the project i have this Error:

> What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
>        Required by:
>            project :
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
>   Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.p
>   om'.

```
  > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
     > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom'
```

.

> Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom'.
>   Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/159.122.18.156] failed: Connection timed out
>   : connect

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error message says that you have internet problem. Not sure how were you able to write this question then ;)

Comment: Can you please show your build file

Comment: @AshishJohn;buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    // Switch the Android Gradle plugin version requirement depending on the
    // installed version of Gradle. This dependency is documented at
    // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility
    // and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8143
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
    }
}
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3.0'
}

Comment: please check if any proxy is needed for accessing internet in android studio and build again

Comment: also replace    2.2.3 with classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3' if you are using Android studio 2.3.3.

Comment: and gradle properties file in gradle folder to distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip

Comment: You installed Android Studio 2.3.3, so you have to change your class path to 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR, I think this is probably because of the networking issue, but you can also use the version (like `2.3.0`) existing in both jcenter() and mavenCentral().

First of all, you have different versions in jcenter() and mavenCentral().

In https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/

```
2.2.0/
2.2.1/
2.2.2/
2.2.3/
2.3.0/
2.3.1/
2.3.2/
2.3.3/
```

In https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/

```
2.0.0/                                            2016-04-07 17:59         -      
2.1.0/                                            2016-04-26 23:02         -      
2.1.2/                                            2016-06-06 18:06         -      
2.1.3/                                            2016-08-24 05:01         -      
2.3.0/                                            2017-03-06 22:09         -
```

Secondly, I think your error is probably due to the networking issue.

`wget https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom` works for me pretty well

```
$ wget https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom
--2017-07-18 08:00:23--  https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom
Resolving jcenter.bintray.com... 75.126.118.188
Connecting to jcenter.bintray.com|75.126.118.188|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Server: nginx
  Date: Tue, 18 Jul 2017 12:00:23 GMT
  Content-Type: application/octet-stream
  Content-Length: 1284
  Connection: keep-alive
  Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="gradle-2.2.3.pom"
  Last-Modified: Tue, 06 Dec 2016 20:27:26 GMT
  Cache-Control: max-age=30, must-revalidate
  Accept-Ranges: none
  ETag: 7c167b79cda55769e0fe6a438f826f203609f1e2db792a93f2b6fae9d71b2259
  X-Checksum-Sha1: 88b4934c958cfe74ff5559c1a33707a562af59d2
  X-Checksum-Sha2: 7c167b79cda55769e0fe6a438f826f203609f1e2db792a93f2b6fae9d71b2259
Length: 1284 (1.3K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘gradle-2.2.3.pom’

gradle-2.2.3.pom                                          100%[====================================================================================================================================>]   1.25K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2017-07-18 08:00:23 (18.0 MB/s) - ‘gradle-2.2.3.pom’ saved [1284/1284]
```

> Could not GET
>   'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom'.
>   Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443
>   [jcenter.bintray.com/159.122.18.156] failed: Connection timed out :
>   connect

However, `ping jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/159.122.18.156]` seems failed for me as well

```
$ ping 159.122.18.156
PING 159.122.18.156 (159.122.18.156): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
^C
--- 159.122.18.156 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

Comment: Thank you it was the firewall

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same pb, as we have a proxy here, which i've configurer in File > Settings I didn't understand why Gradle keeps on telling me there was Connection timeout. I've managed to resolve it adding HTTPS proxy system prop in gradle.properties

```
 systemProp.https.proxyHost=<my proxy hostname>
 systemProp.https.proxyPort=<my proxy port>
```

My gradle.properties contained only the http.proxyHost/Port props...

Answer (score 1):

In my case, comment out the proxy setting in gradle.properties solved the problem.

```
#systemProp.https.proxyPort=8580
#systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
#systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
#systemProp.http.proxyPort=8580
```

Answer (score 0):

in your project level build.gradle file check jcenter() present or not if not  try above code

```
   buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```